# Creating Forms Dynamically in Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I need to create forms dynamically in which the required field parameters will come from the backend. I will use input, dropdown and switch as form elements.

Is there a kendo specific easy way to generate these forms like kendo is doing in listview using template and datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check our [MVVM framework](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/overview) for this. And [some](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/index.html) [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/listview/mvvm.html).